# php checkbox validation code ammendment

Tags: php, ajax, validation, jquery

I am using this code for validating the form input fields using ajax and jquery.... On this page : http://www.kbay.in/ajaxform/index.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//if submit button is clicked
$('#submit').click(function () {        

    //Get the data from all the fields
    var name = $('input[name=name]');
    var phone = $('input[name=phone]');
    var package_name = $('input[name=package_name]');
    var comment = $('input[name=comment]');

    //Simple validation to make sure user entered something
    //If error found, add hightlight class to the text field
    if (name.val()=='') {
        name.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else name.removeClass('hightlight');

    if (phone.val()=='') {
        phone.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else phone.removeClass('hightlight');

    if (package_name.val()=='') {
        package_name.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else package_name.removeClass('hightlight');

    if (comment.val()=='') {
        comment.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else comment.removeClass('hightlight');

    //organize the data properly
    var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&phone=' + phone.val() + '&package_name=' + 
    package_name.val() + '&comment='  + encodeURIComponent(comment.val());
```

But i have add a check box but dont know how to validate it using this script...any ideas....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **is(":checked")**:

```
var commentChecked = $("input[name='comment']").is(':checked'); //returns true or false
var commentVal; //define variable for storing comment value
```

and

```
if (!commentChecked) {
   commentVal = "";
   comment.addClass('hightlight');
   return false;
} else  {
   comment.removeClass('hightlight');
   commentVal = comment.val();;
}
```

And

```
var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&phone=' + phone.val() + '&package_name=' + 
    package_name.val() + '&comment='  + encodeURIComponent(commentVal);
```

Comment: seems to work to an extent...but not completely...thanks...do i have to change  this 
'+ '&comment='  + encodeURIComponent(comment.val());'

 to this 
'+ '&comment='  + encodeURIComponent(!commentChecked);'

Answer (score 1):

Add a checkbox to your HTML... something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ch1">
```

and your jQuery code to check whether it's checked or not should be like the following:

```
if ($("#ch1").prop("checked")) {
    alert("is checked");
}
else {
    alert("is not checked");
}
```